# Problems with MySql remote access

Tags: delphi, xampp, mysql

Top-posted update: apologies for top-posting; the old question is still below for hysterical reasons, but things have changed. This is now more likely a Delphi question than a MySql question.

I find that from the command line I can access a remote MySql database with

```
mysql.exe -h 192.168.89.128 -u my_user -p
```

So it looks like I have correctly set up the remote server.

However, when I try it from Delphi with

```
  AdoConnection.LoginPrompt:=False;//dont ask for the login parameters
  AdoConnection.ConnectionString := 
   Format(MYSQL_CONNECT_STRING,[ConfigurationForm.GetServerIpAddress() + ':3306',
                                DataBase,
                                ConfigurationForm.GetUserName(),
                                ConfigurationForm.GetPassword()]);
  AdoConnection.Connected := True; //open the connection
```

which gives a ConnectionString of

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};  
Server=192.168.89.128:3306;  
Database=mysql;User=my_user;
Password=my_password;Option=3;
```

I get an exception

```
"Unknown MySql server host '192.168.89.128:3306' (11004)"
```

I can has halpz?

---

Update & answer: just in case anyone googles & finds this.

The problem was with my Connection String.

I was appending the port to the host `Server=192.168.89.128:3306;` when I should have specified them separately, i.e `Server=192.168.89.128;Port=3306;`, so that my full connection string is

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};
Server=192.168.89.128;
Port=3306;
Database=mysql;
User=eLogger; 
Password=bct_eLogger;
Option=3;
```

Apologies to those who barked up the wrong tree to try to help me. I hope that this in turn will help some poor Delphi coder. See also http://delphi.about.com/od/mysql/qt/mysqladoconn.htm

Comment: Is port 3306 blocked by either a software or hardware firewall?

Comment: a very good question. But unfortunately I am too dumb to know how to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your problem is which you are including the port in the `server` property, try rewriting you connection string without the `3306` port because this is the default port for mysql or include that port in the `port` property.

something like that

### Without Port

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=192.168.89.128;Database=mysql;User=my_user; Password=my_user;Option=3;
```

### Specifying the TCP/IP port

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=192.168.89.128;Port=3306;Database=mysql;User=my_user; Password=my_user;Option=3;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had only just spotted that & was updating the question as you posted. As always, you have the answers at your fingertips!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if port's open

Execute the following command and look for a ":3306" listener (you did not mention UDP/TCP). This will confirm there is something running on the port.

netstat -a -n

Full answer here on checking ports
https://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-windows

Comment: +1 Thanks. I have updated the question. I found that I can access the remote d/b from the command line, but not form my Delphi program, so I am thinking that maybe I have a bad connect string. Can you take a look, please?